# Flutter: Why DropDownFormField do not change it value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why my drodownformfield do not changed it value?

The dropdown doesn't show it as the chosen one, it just continues as though nothing was selected. Please help me to solve the problem.

```
Widget dropdownstatus(String status) {
    return DropDownFormField(
      titleText: 'Status',
      hintText: 'Sila pilih',
      value: status,
      onSaved: (value) {
        setState(() {
          status = value;
        });
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          status = value;
        });
      },
      dataSource: [
        {
          "display": "Disemak",
          "value": "disemak",
        },
        {
          "display": "Selesai",
          "value": "selesai",
        },
        {
          "display": "Tidak Selesai",
          "value": "tidakselesai",
        },
      ],
      textField: 'display',
      valueField: 'value',
    );
  }
```

From here

```
Container(
      child: widget.list[widget.index]['kategoripengguna'] !='juruteknik'
         ? dropdownstatus(widget.list[widget.index]['status'])
          : TextFormField(
            initialValue: widget.list[widget.index]
             ['status'],
              readOnly: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Status",
               ),
               ),
     ),
```

Comment: can you please show from where the status is passing to this function

Comment: @VilsadPP there i edit the question

Comment: See this answer to update dropDownButton's menuItems,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73194472/10385225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status` is just a parameter of your function. You passed `widget.list[widget.index]['status']` as an argument and only changed the value of this argument throughout your function. So when `setState` is called. It rebuilds the `Container` with the unchanged `widget.list[widget.index]['status']`. In your `onSaved` and `onChanged`, update `widget.list[widget.index]['status']` instead of the argument `status`. This way, when it rebuilds, you will have the updated value stored in `widget.list[widget.index]['status']`, which is the one you will be passing