# DropdownButtonFormField shows error if I changes the list items in getx controller and dropdownFormField has selected an item from that list,

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-getx

I am using DropdownButtonFormField with Getx, when I'm updating item-list of dropdown in controller. Anyone have solution?
My requirement is: a dropdown(showing stats) should be dependent on other dropdown(showing country).

```
child: Obx(
        () =>
        DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          hint: Text('Choose'),
          items: controller.myItemList.map((Item value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value.id.toString(),
              child: new Text(value.Name??""),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            print("selected: " + newValue);
        
          },
        ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the perfect solution for this problem,
Before updating myItemList which is in controller, we need to reset dropdownButtonFormField using it's key,

example:

```
final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _key_dropdown = l̥GlobalKey<FormFieldState>(); //<- add this

child: Obx(
        () =>
        DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
        key: _key_dropdown,   //<------ added this line
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          hint: Text('Choose'),
          items: controller.myItemList.map((Item value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value.id.toString(),
              child: new Text(value.Name??""),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            print("selected: " + newValue);
        
          },
        ),
  ),
```

and before updating the myItemList just need to reset the dropDown using key:

```
_key_dropdown.currentState!.reset(); // reset the dropdown.
```

Comment: this answer solved the same issue for me.thanks